# How to import a typescript module before it is officially added to npm or yarn

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, yarn-v2

I am new to typescript as well as js.  trying to import a module that is being developed, so not yet added to npm.

how do import it to my code?

this is the repo:  adding via yarn doesnt work, how or where do i place this code to be able to import into my code?

https://github.com/xchainjs/xchainjs-lib/tree/549-add-xchainjs-swap-package/packages/xchain-midgard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"dependencies" : {
  "name1" : "git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish",
  "name2" : "git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish"
}
```

Try this.

Comment: thanks, the question is mainly where to fork it?  i notice there is a /node_modules/@xchainjs  folder, should i fork and clone it into this directory?  i dont want to screw up my configs without fully understanding

Comment: updated answer, you can refer to path